# Can't boot into Ubuntu 13.04? GRUB4DOS instead of GRUB2 menu?

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot, 13.04

I am trying to dual boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu 13.04 along side each other. I installed 13.04 to a separate partition on the same hard drive as my Win7 install without any difficulties but after I rebooted it booted immediately into windows. GRUB never showed up.

I downloaded a tool called EasyBCD and added GRUB to the boot as per the instructions I found here: *["Dual-boot Windows 8 and Ubuntu 12.10 on UEFI hardware"](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/11/05/dual-boot-windows-8-and-ubuntu-12-10-on-uefi-hardware/2/)*

When I try and boot into GRUB I get to this screen instead of the standard GRUB menu:

[image: GRUB4DOS boot screen – clipped and brushed]

What do I do at this point? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you install Windows first or second?

Comment: First. I shrunk the partition in windows and installed into the free space.

Comment: Grub4dos is EasyBCD and not related at all to Ubuntu's grub2.

Comment: Check this link and see if this helps.

[http://askubuntu.com/questions/488739/dual-boot-windows-7-and-ubuntu-gnome-14-04-with-easybcd-grub4dos][1]


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/488739/dual-boot-windows-7-and-ubuntu-gnome-14-04-with-easybcd-grub4dos

Answer (score 0):

@Petefic

I used the same document to most part expect the EasyBCD part. Also my dual boot is Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and Windows 8.

Also when I executed boot-repair I did the following.

(Boot Repair => Buggy-kernel detected => Yes)

Good Luck

Comment: Only say yes on "buggy" kernel in Boot-Repair after you confirm that you cannot boot an Ubuntu entry in UEFI menu. That is only for those UEFI systems that modify UEFI to only boot Windows.